# Invoke BPEL from a Webservice in OpenESB

Tags: web-services, bpel, soappy, glassfish-esb, open-esb

Right now i'm developing a composite application using Open ESB. I got my 
application tested through a test case by sending a request SOAP message, 
and it works great.

The problem is, i want my composite application to be able to be used like 
a webservice so i could call the composite application from Python using SOAPpy,
not by sending an edited SOAP message like in the test case.

How can i achieve that? Should i invoke the BPEL process from a webservice?

I already read "A Gentle Introduction: Exploring OpenESB" and "Building SOA-Based 
Composite Applications Using NetBeans IDE 6". Both of the books create an interface 
for the composite application, not using the composite application like a webservice.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: hey please help me out for invoking my bpel application through java code or webservice. when I am going through java code while using Locator class getting classnotfound (even jar included that class) and webservice i dont have much idea(I have generated proxy for my process)

Answer (score 2):

Well, by definition, each BPEL process is rendered as a Web service. In other words: the only possibility to invoke a BPEL process is to invoke the web service interface provided by the BPEL process (the myRole of the partnerlink that is used for inbound message activties). When your test case also submits a SOAP message to the BPEL process, any other Web service client can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer but this can help other users.
Of course they will not use the composite applications as web service simply because it - the composite app - is a client consuming the web service that you have defined using the BPEL ( Business Process Execution **LANGUAGE** ).

Now the question is, how to get the wsdl for our web service ?

Answer :

1. go to your composite application
2. select " wsdl ports " select the wsdl that you have created in "BPEL MODEL" project.
3. right click => properties => location , then copy location value
4. replace {httpdefaultport} by 9080
5. add ?wsdl to the end of the location